# Rollback in burn bootstrappers when user clicks cancel button

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

I've created this installer using burn bootstrapper. Now when a user clicks cancel button, how can I rollback all the changes made during the installation? My EXE currently includes 3 MSIs. So if a user clicks cancel halfway down, how can I remove the previously installed MSIs during this installation? Below is what my cancel button executes.

```
public void ExitExecute()
    {
        CustomBA.BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Burn engine will automatically uninstall all (nonpermanent) packages that were installed during that Apply phase (subject to [RollbackBoundaries](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/rollbackboundary.html)) when an error occurs (canceling is an error).